# How to use PyInstaller from script, not terminal?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

**Short version:**

How do I use PyInstaller from within a Python script, instead of from the terminal?

What would I need to write inside a Python script to get the equivalent of writing this in the terminal:

```
>python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger ../WorkLogger/main.py
```

---

**Long version:**

I'm using a library that requires using PyInstaller to distribute an executable. But I have to run PyInstaller once, then change the spec files, then run the spec file through PyInstaller.

So in the terminal I would've done this:

```
>python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger ../WorkLogger/main.py
```

After this is done running, I manually change the spec file. Then I run:

```
>python -m PyInstaller WorkLogger.spec
```

I've written a script that does the manual labor for me, by running

```
>change_spec.py
```

But I ultimately want to do all of this in one Python script. I want to be able to type something like this:

```
>distribute_python_project.py ./Worklogger
```

This means my Python script would need to look something like this:

```
#Psuedocode:
#python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger ../WorkLogger/main.py
#Code from change_spec.py
#python -m PyInstaller WorkLogger.spec
```

But I can't figure out how I use PyInstaller from a python script, instead of from the terminal. Is this possible? (The library I use is Kivy, for those interested).

Comment: Could you use a subprocess to do the job?

Comment: You could call terminal commands in python script like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I'm able to run the commands with subprocess. But I see now that for me to run the command, I have to be in a specific folder (the terminal has to be cd'd into the folder). Are there any ways you know of to achieve that through subprocess?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Employee and Canh! Working proof of concept:

**Terminal:**

```
>python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger ../WorkLogger/main.py
```

**Python script:**

```
subprocess.call(r"python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger F:\KivyApps\WorkLogger\main.py")
```

If needed, you can **start the subprocess from a specific working directory**:

```
subprocess.call(r"python -m PyInstaller --noconsole --name WorkLogger F:\KivyApps\WorkLogger\main.py", cwd=r"F:\KivyApps\WorkLogger_Dist")
```

Answer (score 9):

Berniiiii's answer was correct but not straight to the point and I personally found it a bit confusing.

this is an answer from the official docs: [running-pyinstaller-from-python-code](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#running-pyinstaller-from-python-code)

```py
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'my_script.py',
    '--onefile',
    '--windowed'
])
```

Is equivalent to:

```py
pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile --windowed
```

Comment: using this approach, how would command look like if I want to add extra search paths, binaries, etc etc? I know this is example from docs and docs dont expalin any complex commands so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Basically any string you would have on the command line, you make an entry in the array:

           PyInstaller.__main__.run([
                'some_script.py',
                '--name', 'my_exe_name',
                '--specpath', 'some_dir',
                '--paths', 'some_other_dir',
                '--onefile',
                '--windowed'
            ])

which means: write the full command line as you normally would, then break it into strings and then add a entry in the array, one for every string

Answer (score 5):

You can even access directly to PyInstaller's module using spec file if you want. In this example this with different locations of spec-file, dist-dir and build-dir.

```js
import PyInstaller

# my spec file in "dev\config" dir
workdir = os.getcwd()
fn_msi_spec = os.path.join(workdir, 'main_msi.spec')

# define the "dev\dist" and "dev\build" dirs
os.chdir("..")
devdir = os.getcwd()
distdir = os.path.join(devdir, 'dist')
builddir = os.path.join(devdir, 'build')

# call pyinstaller directly
PyInstaller.__main__.run(['--distpath', distdir, '--workpath', builddir, fn_msi_spec])
```

Comment: Note: this works but it affects any loggers you have set up.
So for example, logging before PyInstaller.__main__ works fine. Then after the call, any line you add logger.info(xx) will be printed twice. Once by your logger, once by PyInstaller's logger. No idea why...