# Use Auto-py-to-exe from python script?

Tags: python-3.x, exe, file-conversion, auto-py-to-exe

I can successfully convert my .py files to .exe files through the auto-py-to-exe program.

However is there a way to do it completely from a script?

for example:

import auto-py-to-exe

contained file
console type
auto-py-to-exe.convert(fileorigin.py,filedest.exe)

My goal is to have a script constantly running that converts my code then it uploads it to my server. I have the code to upload to the server on timer though i currently have to manually convert my files through the auto-py-to-exe program which is very time consuming and annoying.

If there is another way to do achieve this without auto-py-to-exe I am interested.

Thank you heaps :)

Ive tried googling however i could not find anything.

Comment: At the bottom of the GUI, doesn't it give you a command you can run? If you still need to click the Convert button, maybe try running it in no-chrome mode and using selenium to click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pyinstaller instead. Will post the code when im back on this pc.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-py-to-exe and many other alternatives are using pyinstaller from backend actually.
[There is exist an opened discussion already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636686/how-to-use-pyinstaller-from-script-not-terminal)